# Android App crash on startup because of Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle, onesignal

My app crash on startup because of Firebase and I don't know why. I use in my app OneSignal. I am getting this error messages:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.tosi.man, PID: 1086
              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isDeviceProtectedStorage(Landroid/content/Context;)Z in class Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/com.tosi.man-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1769)
                  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1744)
                  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5990)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5561)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5500)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1595)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:208)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6267)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

This is my build.gradle (Module App):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tosi.man"

        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : 'b53b7c1c-c8c2-4646-a1e8-ea7b4c5d2876',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]

        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 18
        versionName "2.0.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://swisscodemonkeys.github.io/appbrain-sdk/maven'
        }
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.10.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.appbrain:appbrain-sdk:+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:10.39.235.15'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is my build.gradle (Project)

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Can you please help me? I am not sure why I am getting this error maybe I have bad versions of dependencies. Thank you very much.

Comment: A quick tip for you , [Change your target sdk to 26](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html)

Comment: try using firebase 9.
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'`

Answer (score -1):

update few things

1. Google play service
2. Google repository